# Angular $scope.value not updated when value is evaluated and sent via controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq6kucdg/24/) I'm using to learn angular js

In short, `JS` file being used:

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])

.service('myownservice', '$q', function ($timeout, $q) {

    this.httpcall = function() {
         var httpresp = "1818";
         //making an http call over here. 
         return httpresp;
    };

    this.UpdateSomeData = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        myownservice.httpcall().then(function(data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    };
 })
 .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, myownservice) {
    $scope.value = UpdateSomeData();
 });
```

`html page`:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">{{value}}</div>
```

But I'm receiving an error like

`Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string`.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: You should return a **promise**, not `"1818"`!

Comment: shouldn't it be `myownservice.UpdateSomeData()` ?

Comment: Oh, and while you're at it, read about [Promise Anti-patterns](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This had multiple issues.

Firstly, your injections in `myownservice` were not having `[` and `]` and `$timeout` wasn't provided properly.

Next, from within service, you need to access itself by `this` and not name itself.

Next, you need to return a promise from `httpcall` method and not just number.

Here's how it should look like,

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])

.service('myownservice', ['$q', function($q) {
    this.httpcall = function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      var httpresp = "1818";
      defer.resolve(httpresp);
      return defer.promise;
      // replace all this with your $http call and return it..
      // it returns promise itself so you wouldn't need to create on your own
    };

    this.UpdateSomeData = function() {
      return this.httpcall(); 
    };
  }])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, myownservice) {
    myownservice.UpdateSomeData().then(function(val) {
      $scope.value = val
    })
  });
```

[**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gq6kucdg/26/)

Comment: Here we go, this is correct answer. Good that you also cleaned up deferred anti-pattern from `UpdateSomeData`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very generic way to call a HTTP service and return its response. Please try this

```
angular.module('ngApp', []).service('myownservice', '$q', function ($timeout, $q) {
    this.UpdateSomeData = function () {
    return $http.get('URL');
};
```

})

```
 app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, myownservice) {
           $scope.value = myownservice.UpdateSomeData(); // Depends on the 
           response, your $scope.value object has to be declared
 });
```

Comment: `$scope.value = myownservice.UpdateSomeData();` this is wrong (even though earlier Angular versions would unwrap promise's value for you). You should check how to work with promises properly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just return the promise like that. Try with something like so :

```
this.returnUpdateSomeData = function () {
         this.UpdateSomeData().then(function(data) {
                return data;
        });

    };
```

and you missed the myownservice in the controller

```
$scope.value = myownservice.returnUpdateSomeData ();
```

Comment: common , it's just a missedtype, no need to be rude it's not very constructive

Comment: No-no, you didn't understand me: your answer is wrong, you treat promise (async value) like if it was synchronous. It will not work and `$scope.value` will be `undefined` always. Not what OP wants probably. Check this if you want to know how to do it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call